# React Query displaying error component even though I can't see an error in the network tab (all is 200 OK)

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I'm fetching data using a custom hook `useResponses`

```
const {
    data: responses,
    isLoading: isResponsesLoading,
    isError: isResponsesError,
    refetch: refetchResponses,
  } = useResponses(id);
```

For the isError, I'm displaying an error component:

```
if (isResponsesError) {
  return <ErrorMessage refetch={refetchResponses} />;
}
```

My useResponse hook looks like this:

```
export default function useResponses(id) {
  return useQuery(['responses', id], () => getSurveyResponses(id), {
    keepPreviousData: true,
  });
}
```

Every once in a while (and seemingly randomly), the error component is displayed and then when I refetch, it's gone. Looking at the network tab, all the http requests have status 200. What could be causing the error?

This behavior seems to happen especially when I leave the tab for a while and then come back (by clicking the tab). I know React Query has an `refetchOnWindowFocus` default. I want to leave it on. However, I want to fix the error displaying randomly.

Any help is appreciated!

```
const getSurveyResponses = async (id) => {
  try {
    const progressId = await startResponseExport(id);
    const fileId =
      progressId && (await getResponseExportProgress(id, progressId));
    const survey = fileId && (await getResponseExportFile(id, fileId));
    return survey?.responses;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error.message);
  }
};
```

Comment: Perhaps try installing React Query Dev tools for easier debug. In your case, I'd try logging  `isResponseError` and go from there.

Comment: Thanks! I installed react query dev tools and so far all is good

Comment: impossible to say without know what `getSurveyResponses` is doing

Comment: @TkDodo Added getSurveyResponses function

Comment: @TkDodo Btw, thank you for all the great articles on React Query! I've read many of them and they've been really helpful when using React Query!

Comment: After adding this: `const client = new QueryClient({
  defaultOptions: {
    queries: {
      retry: false,
      refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
      staleTime: 30 * 1000,
    },
  },
});` it seems to have stabilized and not getting the error component as often

Comment: with the shown code, you can actually never get the error component, as you are catching errors in the queryFn, which will transform into a fulfilled promise. react-query needs a rejected promise to go into error state. There must be something else going on, like an interceptor or a global onSuccess callback that fails or so. Please show a minimal codesandbox reproduction.

Comment: Interesting, in general, should I not handle errors in axios itself? you mention background errors here https://tkdodo.eu/blog/status-checks-in-react-query How do I silently ignore background errors? You mention checking for data availability first. Does react query expose a boolean for that?